# Faster load fotorama

Tags: jquery, performance, fotorama

I'm wondering how to speed up starting fotorama plugin, because now when I open page I see photo without gallery script for 1 sec and after that gallery will show up.

Example: http://montari.linuxpl.eu/projekty.html

Comment: Have you tried anylizing it via Google Developer Kit Timeline (from Google Chrome, e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/)?

Comment: I haven't, but I found in documentation of fotorama option LAZY LOAD and I used it and works very nice ;)

Comment: That's great, it seems that you initialize your fotorama in onload event then. That's the only reason it could be loaded after your images :-)